# Solely mapping existing db to existing POCOs without designer or CodeFirst in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, entity-framework-6

*One crucial fact @slauma gave in comments. So look at the answer AND comments!*

I'm trying to use components, that are actually used with NHibernate, with the EF6 now. The problem is, I have some TPT inheritances with primary keys of different names. The database and POCO classes are given and I can't change either of them so both CodeFirst and the EF designer are out of question.

Is there a way to just map an existing Db to existing POCO classes, like you do with these .hbm.xml mapping files in NHibernate?

**UPDATE:**

The actual problem I encountered is first of all the TPT mapping of several classes, whereby these classes have differently named primary keys, which seems not to be supported by code first.

So like:

```
public class Record
{
  public virtual int Ndx { get; set; }  // table column 'ndx'

  public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }  // table column 'created'

  // ... further properties
}

public class Patient : Record
{
  public virtual int RecordNdx {get; set;}  // table column 'record_ndx) with FK => records.ndx

  // ... further properties
}
```

And as already said, changing property or column names is not an option.

**Update II:**

This is my registration code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
        .ToTable("record_descriptors", "schema");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
        .HasKey<int>(e => e.ndx);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
        .Property(e => e.read_flag)
        .IsFixedLength()
        .IsUnicode(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
        .Property(e => e.row_version)
        .IsFixedLength();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
        .Property(e => e.update_info)
        .IsUnicode(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
        .ToTable("patienten", "schema");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
        .Property(e => e.mpi)
        .IsUnicode(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
        .Property(e => e.ndx)
        .HasColumnName("record_ndx");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
        .Ignore(r => r.RecordNdx);
}
```

**UPDATE III**

For testing I use:

```
db.patients.First(p => p.Ndx == 6040);
```

And this produces following SQL (more extensive because of real record & patient classes):

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[ndx] AS [ndx], 
    [Limit1].[owner_user_object_ndx] AS [owner_user_object_ndx], 
    [Limit1].[creator_department_user_object_ndx] AS [creator_department_user_object_ndx], 
    [Limit1].[creator_user_user_object_ndx] AS [creator_user_user_object_ndx], 
    [Limit1].[created] AS [created], 
    [Limit1].[read_flag] AS [read_flag], 
    [Limit1].[last_update] AS [last_update], 
    [Limit1].[last_update_user] AS [last_update_user], 
    [Limit1].[last_update_department] AS [last_update_department], 
    [Limit1].[freitext] AS [freitext], 
    [Limit1].[row_version] AS [row_version], 
    [Limit1].[update_info] AS [update_info], 
    [Limit1].[mpi] AS [mpi]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[ndx] AS [ndx], 
        [Extent1].[mpi] AS [mpi], 
        [Extent2].[owner_user_object_ndx] AS [owner_user_object_ndx], 
        [Extent2].[creator_department_user_object_ndx] AS [creator_department_user_object_ndx], 
        [Extent2].[creator_user_user_object_ndx] AS [creator_user_user_object_ndx], 
        [Extent2].[created] AS [created], 
        [Extent2].[read_flag] AS [read_flag], 
        [Extent2].[last_update] AS [last_update], 
        [Extent2].[last_update_user] AS [last_update_user], 
        [Extent2].[last_update_department] AS [last_update_department], 
        [Extent2].[freitext] AS [freitext], 
        [Extent2].[row_version] AS [row_version], 
        [Extent2].[update_info] AS [update_info], 
        '0X0X' AS [C1]
        FROM  [schema].[patienten] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [schema].[record_descriptors] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ndx] = [Extent2].[ndx]
        WHERE 6040 = [Extent1].[ndx]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

which is wrong, as it selects `[ndx]` from `[patienten]` (must be `record_ndx`) and also tries to join over `[ndx]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remark about closing [this work item at CodePlex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/676) claims that **since EF 6** defining different key column names of parent and child entities in a TPT mapping works with Code-First. If that is true the following Code-First mapping should allow to map your model and database:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
    .ToTable("YourRecordTableName");

modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
    .HasKey(r => r.Ndx);

modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
    .Property(r => r.Ndx)
    .HasColumnName("ndx"); // probably redundant because case doesn't matter

modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
    .Property(r => r.CreatedAt)
    .HasColumnName("created");

modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
    .ToTable("YourPatientTableName");

modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
    .Property(r => r.Ndx)   // Yes, no typo: It must be Ndx, NOT RecordNdx !
    .HasColumnName("record_ndx");

modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
    .Ignore(r => r.RecordNdx);
```

The last mapping (ignoring the `RecordNdx` property) is important. It means that your key property will be `Patient.Ndx`. I don't think that you can make any property in a derived class a key property. The key property must always be in the base class of the inheritance hierarchy. However this property can be mapped twice (or generally once per entity in a TPT inheritance chain) to different column names per table - since EF 6.

Getting rid of the `RecordNdx` property completely would be the cleanest solution. But since you said you can't touch your properties it would at least make sense to couple the value of the `RecordNdx` to the `Ndx` property (*if* you can change the property getter and setter):

```
public virtual int RecordNdx
{
    get { return Ndx; }
    set { Ndx = value; }
}
```

**Edit**

I just tested the Code-First mapping above with EF 6.1 and it works indeed! Primary key column in `Record` table is `ndx` and in `Patient` table it is `record_ndx`. Between those EF creates the one-to-one relationship that is required for TPT mapping.

**Edit 2**

That's the complete test program I have used (current EF 6.1 Nuget package, .NET 4.5, VS 2012, SQL Server 2012 Express):

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EFTPT6
{
    public class Record
    {
        public virtual int Ndx { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Patient : Record
    {
        public virtual int RecordNdx { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .ToTable("Records");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .HasKey(r => r.Ndx);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .Property(r => r.Ndx)
                .HasColumnName("ndx");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .Property(r => r.CreatedAt)
                .HasColumnName("created");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
                .ToTable("Patients");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
                .Property(r => r.Ndx)
                .HasColumnName("record_ndx");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
                .Ignore(p => p.RecordNdx);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Initialize(true);
                string sql = ctx.Records.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The string `sql` at the end of the program is:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL)))
        THEN '0X'
        ELSE '0X0X'
    END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[ndx] AS [ndx], 
    [Extent1].[created] AS [created], 
    CASE WHEN ( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL)))
        THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1))
        ELSE [Project1].[Name]
    END AS [C2]
    FROM  [dbo].[Records] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [Extent2].[record_ndx] AS [record_ndx], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Patients] AS [Extent2] ) AS [Project1]
            ON [Extent1].[ndx] = [Project1].[record_ndx]
```

It looks that the mapping is respected, i.e. the `Records` and `Patients` tables are joined by the `ndx` and `record_ndx` column.

**Edit 3**

It's important that the context class does not contain a set for the derived entity, i.e. no `public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }`. If it does the mapping `modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>().Property(r => r.Ndx).HasColumnName("record_ndx");` is ignored and EF expects that the primary key name in `Patient` is `ndx` and not `record_ndx`. For example the last line in the SQL above becomes `ON [Extent1].[ndx] = [Project1].[ndx]`.

Comment: For me it actually still doesn't work, unfortunately. Still SQL code using 'ndx' as pk column for patients is used. Is the order of registrations commands on ModelBuilder important?

Comment: I also tested it with latest beta release 6.1.1 of EF. You don't happen to have your testing code on github, have you? :)

Comment: @AndreasH.: I've posted the test program above and the sql I get for a simple query. Do you use SQL Server or another database/provider?

Comment: I'll try it. SQL Server 2008R2, "System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"; providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient". Interesting is, that VS and ILspy report assembly version 6.0.0 even for the most recent EntityFramework.dll

Comment: So in my test, the produced SQL (which I created like you did) is different, joined via [ndx] == [ndx]. Maybe I need another SQL-Driver or dialect in app.config? And I disabled this Migration mechanism for code first (Database.SetInitializer<CccfkkrDb>(null))

Comment: @AndreasH.: I noticed that you apparently have a `DbSet<Patient> patients` set in your context. If I add that to my test as well I get the same problem like you. So, it seems that you must remove this `patients` set from your context. You can still query for patients by using `db.Records.OfType<Patient>()...` It's a bit weird that the existence of this set (even if not used) causes wrong SQL. Looks like an EF bug to me.